# Creating a table from the output of advanced filter copy

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I managed to use AdvancedFilter to only copy certain data that meets my criteria to a existing worksheet using the following snippet.

```
Sheets("MyDataSheet").Range("MainTable[#All]").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Criteria").Range( _
        "Criteria[[#All],[MyFilter]]"), CopyToRange:=Range("Test!Extract"), _
        Unique:=False
```

However, on that sheet is an existing table. When i run this macro the correct data is copied but it isn't a table. Can somebody help me convert the output to a table with a specified name.

Status is that there is already a table with that name (target name: "FilteredTable"). table can be emptied and than pasted with the new filtered data.

Comment: You could record a macro while converting the copied data to a table - that should give you what you need.

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried that but in the macro it uses select cell a1:.. but that range is different everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
           .Range("Extract").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Blah"

End With
```